# How to remove extra whitespace on pie charts from MpAndroidCharts?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

So I have a `PieChart` that is using `setMaxAngle` to create something like a gauge.  However, there is significant whitespace under it that I need to remove.  I can't find any methods to modify the viewport for `PieChart`.  So how can I refer the white space?  See pic below.

[image]

My layout is the following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.nextraq.anders.ui.dashboard.DashboardActivityFragment"
tools:showIn="@layout/dashboard_activity">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    style="@style/AndersMaterialTheme.Dashboard.Gadget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:padding="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gadgetTitle"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/mobiles"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
            android:id="@+id/mobileStateChart"
            android:layout_below="@id/gadgetTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
PieDataSet dataset = new PieDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");

dataset.setSliceSpace(0f);
```

I hope you that helpful

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not what I was referring to.  I was talking about the very large whitespace below the pie chart.  The white space below the text "85 Mobiles".  Not the spaces between each pie slice.